# Domain for fetching records from specified date range returns records outside that range

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8, xml-rpc

I'm trying to fetch data from Odoo8 database using XML-RPC.

I have request like this written in Python:

```py
common = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy('{}/xmlrpc/2/common'.format(url))
uid = common.authenticate(db, username, password, {})

models = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy('{}/xmlrpc/2/object'.format(url))
test = models.execute_kw(db, uid, password,
    'calendar.event', 'search_read',
    [['&',['start_datetime', '>=', '2019-09-03 00:00:00'],['stop_datetime', '<', '2019-09-10 00:00:00']]],
    {'fields': ['allday', 'start_datetime', 'start_date', 'stop_datetime'], 'limit': 5})
```

But I get records that exceed requested date range.

[image]

I also tried to use date instead datetime (this fields are used when event is marked as all day) but does not work as well.

I’m using hard-coded string just for testing. Ultimately I will use something like this:

```py
datetime.today().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

How do I fetch data only from desired date range?

Comment: You can remove `&` it's applied by default, Your code should work perfectly!! I don't see the problem here, can you put the entire code?

Comment: @ElegantOdoo: Entire code isn't much different because I'm only running small python script (from the console) just for testing purposes.
https://pastebin.com/CLLxiF8L

Comment: Just remove the `&` and make sure you didn't override search_read or any method that changes the domain passed to the method. just debug more to see what is the final domain passed to search read in models.Model class. set a break point in search_read method and see what is the domain passed to it

Comment: @ElegantOdoo This is an old instance of Odoo 8 hosted by external company so I don’t really have access other than xml-rpc requests and web UI. I tried this request on my Odoo12 testing instance with `__last_update` and it has similar problem:. https://pastebin.com/QCwiEjYs. But I’ve also tested in with `request_date` and it seems to work: https://pastebin.com/JyWE0ZFu.

Comment: Are this field computed or normal fields?

Comment: I'm not sure, but the difference I saw between `__last_update` and `request_date` is that the `request_date` is stored and  `__last_update` is not.

Comment: yes I know computed field must be stored so you can use them in search method, they are not database field they are just class field, but when I checked the fields in github they where not computed, witch version of Odoo they are using exactly to understand what is happening

Comment: I know only it is Odoo 8. I don't know the exact version/build.

Comment: use the common.version() you will find example in Odoo api tutorials

Comment: @ElegantOdoo `{'server_version_info': [8, 0, 0, 'final', 0], 'server_serie': '8.0', 'server_version': '8.0', 'protocol_version': 1}`

Comment: I thought it will return the date of version sorry, I just want to know if this field are computed or not, try to use filter with other field if the domain works fine then this field are not stored in database, so you have to figure out how to change your domain with other fields

Comment: It would return that in newer versions. But I just found out that there are not only `start_date` and `start_datetime` there is also field called `start` (and analogous field for `stop`) and **they are working**!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found the solution.

I was trying to use `start_date` or `start_datetime` inside my domain but actually there is **another field called just `start` which is working fine** (or `stop` for that matter if stop date is what you are looking for).

Opposed to `start_date` and `start_datetime` it is *stored* field so it can be used inside domain.

This is how modified request would look like:

```py
models = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy('{}/xmlrpc/2/object'.format(url))
test = models.execute_kw(db, uid, password,
    'calendar.event', 'search_read',
    [[['start', '>=', '2019-09-01 00:00:00'],['start', '<=', '2019-09-08 00:00:00']]],
    {'fields': ['name', 'allday', 'start', 'stop']})
```

Thanks to @Elegant Odoo for the help and pushing me on the right track.